# Django: Why do I get syntax error for the new url in django 1.9?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

With the old syntax in Django 1.7 this example worked, but can you spot any syntax mistake:

**mysite/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^list/', include('new_app.urls')),
]
```

**new_app/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), # hello world function, it works!
    url(r'^long_list', ListView.as_view(model=NewModel, template_name='new_app/list.html', name='list'),
] #invalid syntax (urls.py, line 14) #displayed in my browser, points to this line
```

I didn't upgrade my old Django which is on another PC, I just recreated this model. I guess all the other settings are right in the new installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url(r'^long_list', ListView.as_view(...)),
                                        ^
                                        |__ You forgot this closing 
                                            parenthesis
```

Comment: Thank you for being so explicit, I observed the mistake before I got answers. But I've spent much longer before without seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

Add closing bracket in line 14 )